A Method for Functional Misspecification
I have been thinking about unbiasedness recently. An idea for came to my mind . Imagine that the dataset is separated into three different parts as training, the data that will be added to training set and test set. Primarly we modify and construct the linear model.
As we include additional observations to the training set, the estimates will change. If the estimates that was acquired from the dataset after additional observations included outperform the estimates of restricted dataset in terms of estimation of test set (let's say lower SSR), then can we assume that the model that was specified initially is unbiased and doesn't have functional misspecification (regarding it fulfill assumptions for unbiased estimators)? And is it a useful solution for the functional misspecification problems?

The specification doesn't change as we add more obs??? What do you mean when you say "estimates that was acquired from the dataset after additional observations included outperform the estimates of restricted dataset in terms of estimation of test set" - estimates are coefficients, right?

No, I tried to explain that as we add more observations we would expect to see more significant results given a specific functional form of a model, since we model a function a priori. But as we add more observation and run the regression according to the specified functional form, then it will be wise to expect lower residuals when it comes to estimating the test set. My question is that does this situation indicate that we modeled correct functional form.

I don't see how this has any advantages over using the data sets separately, and it seems harder to interpret.
